# Stop thread group after some time - jmeter

Tags: java, batch-file, jmeter

I have a Thread group which contain a OS Process Sampler. This sampler runs a bat file which in turn runs another bat file. Second bat file will start a java spring boot application. Now my thread group never stops until I close the cmd opened for running the java app. I want to stop this TG after some time so that I can start another TG. Tried below things.

1. Configuring 'Duration(seconds)' on TG level.
2. Configuring 'Timeout(ms)' on OS Process Sampler.
3. Putting OS Process Sampler as a child of Runtime Controller.

None of the above approach worked.
For reference find sample batFile1, batFile2 and batFile3

**batFile1.bat**

```
start cmd /k call batFile2.bat
```

**batFile2.bat**

```
java -jar -Dserver.port=8081 -DfileName=<path to jar>
```

Jmeter version - 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your test will run until your Spring Boot application runs.
2. `/k` switch means that OS Process Sampler will exit only when you manually close the "cmd.exe" window.

---

Depending on what you're trying to achieve:

1. If your Spring Boot application exits itself after doing some job - just change `/k` to `/c` and this way the OS Process Sampler will end as soon as Spring Boot application finishes its job. See [cmd.exe syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) for more information on what do these keys mean
2. If your Spring Boot application doesn't stop you can kill it from another Thread Group using [taskkill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill) command
3. In any way it's [recommended to always use the latest version of JMeter where/if possible](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling) so consider migrating to [JMeter 5.6.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/o906of55x1n8z2zm8fyj3w9k3lqf8y0c) or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page.